# Nesting SVGs causes unexpected resizing

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to use nested inline SVGs in order to flexibly arrange smaller svg images within an svg container. However, I am struggling to understand the rules of how nested SVGs are sized.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
```

Why does this correctly display a 200px by 200px red square:

```html
<svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

But why does wrapping in another svg element cause the square to become 150px by 150px?
for example:

```html
<svg>
  <svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

or:

```html
<svg width="200px">
  <svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

or:

```html
<svg width="200px">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you don't specify a height and width an <svg> element defaults to 300px x 150px. Everything else follows from that, no?

Comment: I spent a third of an entire evening several days ago wrestling with a canvas image which was displaying incorrectly (I'm currently learning how to use HTML5 Canvas) before discovering that the `<canvas>` element _also_ defaults to `300px x 150px`. (I guess I've always given my SVGs explicit dimensions, because I didn't know this applied to SVGs too). There _must_ be an historic reason for these default dimensions.

Comment: Excuse me if im wrong but im trying to replicate your problem in jsfiddle, only it doesnt show up. Anyway you can show it to us?

Comment: @Rounin all replaced elements obey that rule and <svg> and <canvas> are both replaced elements in the CSS specification.

Comment: @RobertLongson - good to know, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `width` and the `height` of each successive `<rect>` but be sure to maintain the same `width` and `viewbox` of each nested parent `<svg>` every time.

**Working Example:**

```html
<svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">

  <rect width="200" height="200" fill="red" />
  
  <svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" />
  
    <svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    
      <svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      
        <rect width="25" height="25" fill="yellow" />
      
        <svg width="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">

          <rect width="12.5" height="12.5" fill="red" />

        </svg>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```